# Problem running stage navigation tutorial

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, stage, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

I'm trying to execute the code from "Tutorials/stage and navigation stack", roslaunch awesomeros robot.launch

started roslaunch server http://istvan-System-Product-Name:56169/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /use_sim_time
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/observation_sources
- /amcl/gui_publish_rate
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/origin_y
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/origin_x
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/update_frequency
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/origin_z
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/max_obstacle_height
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/origin_z
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/marking
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/observation_sources
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vx_samples
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/raytrace_range
- /amcl/recovery_alpha_slow
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/clearing
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/mark_threshold
- /amcl/laser_z_short
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/max_obstacle_height
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x
- /amcl/laser_z_max
- /amcl/laser_z_rand
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_th
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/observation_persistence
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/inflation_radius
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/map_type
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_y
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/static_map
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/data_type
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/min_obstacle_height
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/footprint
- /amcl/laser_lambda_short
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/observation_persistence
- /amcl/laser_max_beams
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/z_resolution
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/map_type
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/lethal_cost_threshold
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/heading_lookahead
- /amcl/odom_model_type
- /amcl/laser_sigma_hit
- /amcl/recovery_alpha_fast
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/inflation_radius
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/z_voxels
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/data_type
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/transform_tolerance
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/robot_base_frame
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/transform_tolerance
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/global_frame
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/rolling_window
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/dwa
- /amcl/odom_alpha5
- /amcl/odom_alpha1
- /amcl/odom_alpha2
- /amcl/odom_alpha3
- /amcl/odom_alpha4
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/width
- /stageros/base_watchdog_timeout
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/clearing
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/publish_frequency
- /amcl/max_particles
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/height
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/obstacle_range
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/static_map
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/cost_scaling_factor
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance
- /amcl/min_particles
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/global_frame
- /move_base_node/controller_frequency
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/cost_scaling_factor
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_rotational_vel
- /amcl/laser_model_type
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/publish_frequency
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias
- /amcl/transform_tolerance
- /amcl/kld_err
- /amcl/resample_interval
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/update_frequency
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/obstacle_range
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/mark_threshold
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/max_obstacle_height
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/vtheta_samples
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/robot_base_frame
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/lethal_cost_threshold
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/z_resolution
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/footprint
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/rolling_window
- /amcl/laser_z_hit
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/expected_update_rate
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/raytrace_range
- /amcl/update_min_d
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_rotational_vel
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/unknown_threshold
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/path_distance_bias
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/max_obstacle_height
- /amcl/odom_frame_id
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/unknown_threshold
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/marking
- /move_base_node/NavfnROS/allow_unknown
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/base_scan/min_obstacle_height
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/z_voxels
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/resolution
- /move_base_node/footprint_padding
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/backup_vel
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist
- /amcl/kld_z
- /move_base_node/global_costmap/footprint_padding
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/base_scan/expected_update_rate
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/footprint_padding
- /amcl/update_min_a
- /amcl/laser_likelihood_max_dist
- /move_base_node/local_costmap/publish_voxel_map
- /amcl/initial_pose_x
- /amcl/initial_pose_y
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/occdist_scale
- /move_base_node/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance

NODES
/
move_base_node (move_base/move_base)
map_server (map_server/map_server)
stageros (stage/stageros)
amcl (amcl/amcl)
/local_costmap/
voxel_grid_throttle (topic_tools/throttle)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://istvan-System-Product-Name:11311/

core service [/rosout] found
process[voxel_grid_throttle-1]: started with pid [10804]
process[move_base_node-2]: started with pid [10805]
process[map_server-3]: started with pid [10806]
process[stageros-4]: started with pid [10807]
process[amcl-5]: started with pid [10814]
err: /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ros_tutorials/awesomeros/world/willow.world:21 : syntax error 2 (/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-stage-1.2.4/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-stage/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_stage/stage/build/Stage-3.2.2-Source/libstage/worldfile.cc ParseTokenWord)

[ INFO] [1298482640.454591335, 2.700000000]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan
[ WARN] [1298482645.543905205, 7.800000000]: Waiting on transform from base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Frame id /base_link does not exist!

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9183/problem-running-stage-navigation-tutorial/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, the [move_base_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base_stage) package is deprecated. You should look into the [navigation_stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_stage) package for newer example launch files.

Now, for your actual problem. That world file in the tutorial is likely an old, out of date World file format. To fix this, try running the `upgrade-world.sh` file available in the `stage` package. For example,

```
rosrun stage upgrade-world.sh willow.world willow-new.world
```

and then try using `willow-new.world` instead of `willow.world`.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3